# How to fix a cyrillic character/utf encoding issue in php

Tags: php, mysql, database, encoding

I'm trying to access a table which is named, say, "Вильгельм_Телль". So I do the following:

`$group = "Вильгельм_Телль";
$msql = "SELECT result FROM $group";`

What I get is:

> check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '�ильгельм_Телль' at line 1

Extra information:

- The issue only seems to affect only the first character of the string
- My meta charset is set to UTF8
- My PHP charset is set to UTF8 using mysqli_set_charset, I get the same result using 'header (...)'
- My file is saved as UTF8 without BOM
- I'm using WAMP to serve my page
- EDIT: it doesn't work as one-word either

Comment: with a 2 word table name you need back ticks

Comment: It's not "2 words"; it has an underscore.

Comment: (Neither of the "duplicate" questions were relevant, so I voted for reopening.)

Comment: Please provide `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'char%';`.  Tell us which PHP API you are using.  _It had better not be `mysql*`._  `mysqli*` is OK.  Show us the connection parameters.

Comment: Also, do `echo bin2hex($group);`.  If it does not start with `d092d0b8...`, that will be a good clue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use `` (quote identifier) for sql queries.

```
SELECT * FROM `Вильгельм Телль`
```

Recommendation: do not use anything other ansi characters for table names, columns etc. You may face problems in other apps, cli etc.

Comment: Not relevant since there is an underscore in the name.